# ExoPlayer 2 Playlist Listener

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm using the new features from ExoPlayer 2.x to play a list of audio files like this:

```
List<MediaSource> playlist = new ArrayList<>();

...

ConcatenatingMediaSource concatenatedSource = new ConcatenatingMediaSource(
            playlist.toArray(new MediaSource[playlist.size()]));

mExoPlayer.prepare(concatenatedSource);
mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

This is working fine, but in order to update my UI accordingly, I need to know which track is currently playing and the progress of this track. Is there any listener from ExoPlayer?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this? The accepted answer doesn't help, as noted in the comments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So I am in a similar scenario and need to know when the next video in the playlist starts. I found that the `ExoPlayer.EventListener` has a method called `onPositionDiscontinuity()` that gets called every time the video changes or "seeks" to the next in the playlist.

I haven't played around with this method extensively, but from what I can see so far, this is the method that you should be concerned about. There are no parameters that get passed when the method is fired, so you'll have to keep some kind of counter or queue to keep track of whats being played at any given moment.

Hopefully this helps!

**Edit:** change in index returned by `Exoplayer.getCurrentWindowIndex()` is the [recommended way](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2053#issuecomment-259521287) to detect item change in a playlist `MediaSource`.

```
int lastWindowIndex = 0; // global var in your class encapsulating exoplayer obj (Activity, etc.)

exoPlayer.addListener(new ExoPlayer.EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {
            //THIS METHOD GETS CALLED FOR EVERY NEW SOURCE THAT IS PLAYED
            int latestWindowIndex = exoPlayer.getCurrentWindowIndex();
            if (latestWindowIndex != lastWindowIndex) {
                // item selected in playlist has changed, handle here
                lastWindowIndex = latestWindowIndex;
                // ...
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: that method also called when you do fastforward or rewind.. so it doesn't work for me :( I need a listener that only fired when a new video started B-(

Comment: What you might try is wrapping the above code into a custom ExoPlayer class. In that class you could maintain the objects needed to play/fast-forward/rewind the video thats playing, and only perform actions in the onPositionDiscontinuity() method when the video is playing normally, and not fast-forwarding/rewinding. Basically you'd have logic in the onPositionDiscontinuity() method that checks if the video is fast-forwarding or rewinding, and only proceed if both of those cases are false.

Comment: This worked for info ... thanks a lot for the guidance :)

Answer (score 12):

You can implement the following event and update your ui according to the player's state.

```
 mExoPlayer.addListener(new ExoPlayer.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                if (playbackState == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING) {
                    //do something                 
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayWhenReadyCommitted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
                mExoPlayer.stop();

            }
        });
```

Comment: How do I know which track is playing?

Comment: One way to handle this is to save the current playing song in the cache. When the player status is being changed you can fire an event to show the current song.

Comment: @DoronKakuli but `onPositionDiscontinuity` is called when Exoplayer is ready to play the song, not when next button is click then how to handle & update UI ??

Comment: @timoschloesser use Player.getCurrentMediaItem (https://exoplayer.dev/playlists.html)

Answer (score 1):

Since the answer here did not work for me, I will add my working solution in Kotlin.
And also there are lots of methods deprecated since then.

You can track the current track(video) by setting a mediaId when creating your playlist

Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.14.1'
```

Layout xml:

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/player_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:show_buffering="when_playing"/>
```

Code:

```
private lateinit var exoPlayer: SimpleExoPlayer
private lateinit var playerView: PlayerView
private lateinit var fileList: List<FileModel>

private fun initPlayer() {
    playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view)
    playerView.controllerShowTimeoutMs = 0
    playerView.cameraDistance = 30F
    exoPlayer = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
    playerView.player = exoPlayer

    setPlaylist()
    exoPlayer.prepare()
    exoPlayer.seekTo(position, C.TIME_UNSET) // position = current song or video
    exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
    addPlayerListeners()
}

private fun setPlaylist() {
    for ((pos, file) in fileList.withIndex()) {
        val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder().setUri(file.url).setMediaId(pos.toString()).build()
        exoPlayer.addMediaItem(mediaItem)
    }
}

private fun addPlayerListeners() {
    exoPlayer.addListener(object : Player.Listener{
        override fun onMediaItemTransition(mediaItem: MediaItem?, reason: Int) {
            super.onMediaItemTransition(mediaItem, reason)
            val  item = mediaItem?.mediaMetadata
            val bmp = item?.artworkData
            Log.i(TAG, "position = ${mediaItem?.mediaId}")
            val currentPos = mediaItem?.mediaId
            updateViews(currentPos, bmp)
        }
    })
}

private fun updateViews(currentPos: String?, bmp: ByteArray?) {
    position = currentPos?.toInt() ?: 0
    val title = fileList[position].title
    textview_title.text = title

    if (bmp == null) {
        image_view.setImageResource(R.drawable.exo_ic_default_album_image)
        return
    }
    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bmp, 0, bmp.size)
    image_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Kotlin, it looks like this:

```
 player?.addListener(object : Player.Listener {
        
        override fun onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying: Boolean) {
            super.onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying)
            _isPlaying.postValue(isPlaying)
        }

        fun onPlayerError(error: ExoPlaybackException?) {
            player?.stop()
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  player.getCurrentMediaItemIndex();
```

Return the index of current item in your play list.

```
  player.getCurrentPosition();
```

returns the time position of your item which is playing in milliseconds.