# How to add Listener for next , previous , rewind and forward in Exoplayer

Tags: android, listener, controls, exoplayer

I am working on ExoPlayer, I want to customize the ExoPlayer and listen for the Event next, previous, rewind, forward so that when the user clicks the next button next video in the Playlist will be playing and when using previous the previous video in the playlist will be playing and so on. I am using the Custom Layout, it changes the design but not listen for these events(next, previous etc). here is my code:-

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:keepScreenOn="true">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:resize_mode="fill"
        app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_controls"
        app:player_layout_id="@layout/custom_player_view"
        app:surface_type="texture_view"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</RelativeLayout>




<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

I have added the list of Mediasource in  ConcatenatingMediaSource. It is working but I am to change the layout also, that why I need a listener for every control in ExoPlayer. I see this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284772/exoplayer-2-playlist-listener). So I  know onPositionDiscontinuity() method calls every time when the user clicks on next, previous, rewind, forward button in ExoPlayer But I want listener for each button so I can perform the appropriate action??

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this [link](https://github.com/yusufcakmak/ExoPlayerSample) to customize the ExoPlayer for previous, next etc. You can implement your own logic to track all of these Events. It works for me.

Comment: Is it possible to create our own PlaybackControlView class?

Answer (score 3):

My approach

Assumed, we are already create collection of media source, DASH or HLS.

And using player view with `SimpleExoPlayerView` component. It will automatically have default control, prev, next, for example.

I handle collection of media source with current window index with this `exoPlayer.getCurrentWindowIndex()` to back and forth media source.

And you can check current index via this `onTracksChanged` method

```
@Override
public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

currentIndex = exoPlayer.getCurrentWindowIndex();

}
```

You can look this [file](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/3ada4e178dc320abb73c01ec7bdf4535334e0a3d/library/ui/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlaybackControlView.java#L944) for implementation these control.

Hope this help.

Comment: Since that currentWindowIndex is deprecated, use currentMediaItemIndex instead

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to add a `ExoPlayer.Listener()` and use constants from the [`PlaybackstateCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/PlaybackStateCompat.html#STATE_FAST_FORWARDING) class.

Override the `onPlayerStateChanged` listener and check the `playbackState` with **rewind/fastforward/etc**

```
 player.addListener(new ExoPlayer.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                if (playbackState == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_FAST_FORWARDING) {
                    //do something                 
                }
                if (playbackState == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_REWINDING) {
                    //do something else               
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayWhenReadyCommitted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
                mExoPlayer.stop();

            }
        });
```

Also:

1. `STATE_SKIPPING_TO_NEXT`
2. `STATE_SKIPPING_TO_PREVIOUS`

Answer (score 0):

Best approach for intercepting the exoplayer's control UI events is to add a custom dispatcher.

`mBinding.styledPlayerView.setControlDispatcher(CustomControlDispatcher())`

```
class CustomControlDispatcher(): DefaultControlDispatcher() {

    override fun dispatchFastForward(player: Player): Boolean {
        Logger.d(TAG, "dispatchFastForward")
        return super.dispatchFastForward(player)
    }

    override fun dispatchRewind(player: Player): Boolean {
        Logger.d(TAG, "dispatchRewind")
        return super.dispatchRewind(player)
    }

}
```

Comment: ControlDispatcher and its subclasses have now been removed from ExoPlayer

Comment: @ilansas What can we do now for this?

Comment: As specified in the release notes, you now have to use a `ForwardingPlayer` to which you pass your instance of ExoPlayer, and then override its methods of rewind and fast forward

Answer (score 0):

For rewind and Forward feature, I think this might help you >> [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73007667/11485806)

I use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73007667/11485806) to add the **Rewind** and **Forward** Feature in ExoPlayer or ExoPlayer2. You can implement your own logic to track all of these Events. It works for me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32264060)

Answer (score -1):

```
 if you have not customized exoplayer



    if (currentPlayingVodPosition-1 == player.currentWindowIndex){
 Toast.makeText(this,"prev clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    }
if (currentPlayingVodPosition+1 == player.currentWindowIndex){
   Toast.makeText(this,"next clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    }
```