# ExoPlayer: Control skip-interval for forward and rewind buttons

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm looking for a way to set a skip interval for "forward" and "rewind" buttons. By default pressing forward skips 15 seconds of video, but pressing rewind skips only 5 seconds. I'd like to set both to 5 seconds but I can't find any API to do so.

**Question:** How to override skip-interval for "forward" and "rewind" buttons in ExoPlayer 2?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should be  **app:fastforward_increment="5000"** and **app:rewind_increment="5000"**

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
                    android:id="@+id/item_comment_exo_player_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/black"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                    android:paddingStart="0dp"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp"
                    app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_playback_control"
                    app:fastforward_increment="5000"
                    app:rewind_increment="5000"
                    app:show_timeout="2000" />
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding it to `SimpleExoPlayerView ` didn't help, but once I added it to `PlayerControlView` it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the XML attributes specified but still face the same issue i.e. **pressing forward skips 15 seconds of video, but pressing rewind skips only 5 seconds**.

so I override the values of the attributes in Java code **to set both to skip 5 seconds only**.

```
// This will override the player controller XML attributes.
    playerView.setFastForwardIncrementMs(5000);
    playerView.setRewindIncrementMs(5000);
```

For more references [check official doc](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerControlView.html#DEFAULT_FAST_FORWARD_MS).

Comment: Deprecated code

Answer (score 0):

**app:fastforward_increment="5000"** and **app:rewind_increment="5000"** is now Deprecated code instead of use [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73007667/11485806) to implement rewind and forward feature.

Just add this code on your button onclick listener.

```
//switch case onClick listener for 'Forward' and 'Rewind'

    case R.id.exo_rewind:
            int rewind = (int) player.getCurrentPosition();
            rewind = rewind - 10000; // 10000 = 10 Seconds
            player.seekTo(rewind);
        break;

    case R.id.exo_forward:
            int forward = (int) player.getCurrentPosition();
            forward = forward + 10000; // 10000 = 10 Seconds
            player.seekTo(forward);
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

`setFastForwardIncrementMs` (or `app:fastforward_increment`) and `setRewindIncrementMs` (or `app:rewind_increment`) don't exist anymore.

In Media3 ExoPlayer you can set the interval while building the player:

```
Player player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
        .setSeekForwardIncrementMs(10000L)
        .setSeekBackIncrementMs(10000L)
        .build();
```